# How to report bugs in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I have noticed that using Markdown support in Tumblr, there is a problem with code formatting.  For example, in this post:

> http://randomencoding.tumblr.com/post/35672522660/android-programatically-setting-up-a-tabhost

I've used the Markdown support in my code snippet.   You'll notice that the code starts out like this:

```
 TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
```

There's an annoying space in the front of the first line.  If I try to delete that space (by shrinking my first-line-indent from 4 spaces to 3) you'll not be surprised to learn that this makes it so that the snippet is no longer considered code and is thus formatted incorrectly.

I do not expect a solution to this bug here -- but how do I report this bug to Tumblr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with Tumblr are best submitted via the "Contact Support" link at the bottom of their [help page](http://www.tumblr.com/help).

There is also an old [Get Satisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/tumblr/) page, but this doesn't appear to get much use any more.

Comment: Note that the "Contact Support" link might be hidden on their help page (for me, at least). I had to disable CSS to be able to see/click it.

Comment: Good heavens that was hard to find!  But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, I just discovered that if you type "Report a bug" into the search bar at the top of [their help page](http://www.tumblr.com/help), then the "Contact Support" button will appear at the bottom of the page.